# Question about state-value function in RL - doesn't first sum always equal 1 by definition?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, reinforcement-learning

I'm going through the textbook `Reinforcement Learning` by Sutton and Barto ([available online](http://incompleteideas.net/book/RLbook2018.pdf)), and equation 4.4 shows "the state-value function $v_\pi$ for an arbitrary policy $\pi$":

$v_\pi = \sum\limits_a \pi(a|s) \sum\limits_{s',r}p(s',r|s,a) [r + \gamma v_\pi(s')]
$

"where $\pi(a|s)$ is the probability of taking action $a$ in state $s$ under policy $\pi$."

My question is: isn't the first sum -- $\sum\limits_a \pi(a|s)$ -- always equal to 1? Like, the probabilities of taking some action given a particular state, across all actions available in that state, must sum to 1 (100%) right? Even "no action" would be an "action" in this context, if I understand correctly, such that the probabilities would always sum to 1.

So it seems to me either I must be wrong and that doesn't always sum to 1, or if I'm right, I don't understand the purpose of adding the extra term to the equation, if it just multiplies the second sum by 1 always.

Any helpful explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: the second sum is inside the scope of the first

Comment: Oh of course. Awesome, thanks! If you want to post that as an answer I'll accept it